# fig-width doesn't change size of Mermaid in reveal.js

Tags: r, quarto, reveal.js, mermaid

I would like to change the output size of my mermaid diagram using `fig-width` but nothing happens. It doesn't work in both Rstudio and VScode. Here is some reproducible code:

````
--- 
format: revealjs
---

## Mermaid doesn't change size

```{mermaid}
flowchart LR
  A[Hard edge] --> B(Round edge)
  B --> C{Decision}
```
````

Output:

[image]

Using `fig-width` like this:

````
--- 
format: revealjs
---

## Mermaid doesn't change size

```{mermaid}
%%| fig-width: 12
flowchart LR
  A[Hard edge] --> B(Round edge)
  B --> C{Decision}
```
````

Output:

[image]

As you can see nothing changes. I'm using `Quarto 1.4.537` as the version. So I was wondering if anyone knows why this doesn't work?